# Resize ImageView height to fill remaining space

Tags: android-constraintlayout

What's the best option to get ImageView take remaining space giving room for rest of the UI elements inside ConstraintLayout? By the below layout, the ImageView doesn't budge and takes space before giving space to its siblings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/story_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bg">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/story_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/story_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/story_title_padding_top"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/story_title"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/story_image"
        app:lineHeight="@dimen/story_title_line_spacing" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/story_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/story_body_padding_top"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/story_body"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/story_body"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/story_title"
        app:lineHeight="@dimen/story_body_line_spacing" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/story_meta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="12sp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="@dimen/story_footer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the below screenshot(iOS), the top image yields to bottom text and made itself small. This what expected.
[image]

In the below screenshot(Android), the top image takes all space and not yielding to bottom text which gets truncated. This needs fix.

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image/ drawing of your desired look vs what you have now?

Comment: Are you willing to risk shrinking the image to almost non visible dimensions while trying to fit all the text into a small screen device?

Comment: you should use `linearlayout` with weights for achieving this

Comment: @RaymondArteaga Yes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, and I'm not exactly an expert but I'm linking some documentation about the command from various sources here
Documentation from Android Developers website: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView
Documentation from Another developer website: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/imageview
I don't entirely know what this is but try the commands `android:adjustViewBounds` or `android:scaleType` to achieve your desired results.

Comment: From the question you can see that I have tried as you suggested, none works

Comment: @Vjy I linked some documentation that may help